# :root css with "--" attributes, how does it work

Tags: css

I ran into some css that detailed some colors for :root.  I don't understand how to use it.  How would I call the `--pelorous` color?

```
:root {
    --cerulean: #0571AE;
    --ivory: #FDFDFC;
    --regal-blue: #1A3852;
    --bondi-blue: #0082C3;
    --pelorous: #1E8FD0;
    --light-grey: #D5D4D4;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables

Answer (score 4):

This would be the format, in combination with the var() function:

```
.myElement { color: var(--pelorous); }
```

More info [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#using-variables) and [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

Answer (score 1):

What those properties are called is CSS Variables, when fully supported by browsers, they will offer a solution to avoid repetition throughout your CSS file.

These variables should be defined inside the `:root` selector.

In order to replace a property value with a variable you need to use the `var()` CSS function.

---

### SYNTAX

```
selector { property: var(custom-property-name, declaration-value) }
```

---

### DEMO:

```css
:root {
  --cerulean: #0571AE;
  --ivory: #FDFDFC;
  --regal-blue: #1A3852;
  --bondi-blue: #0082C3;
  --pelorous: #1E8FD0;
  --light-grey: #D5D4D4;
  --demo-height: 50vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: var(--demo-height);
}
div {
  flex: 0 0 10%;
  background-color: var(--light-grey);
}
div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: var(--regal-blue);
}
.container:nth-child(2) div {
  background-color: var(--pelorous);
}
.container:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: var(--bondi-blue);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
<section class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</section>
```

---

### BROWSER SUPPPORT:

[**caniuse**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables)

---

### MORE INFO:

[Var() MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

[Using CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)

[W3 CSS Custom Properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/)